# Why can't we sort N numbers in comparison sorting algorithm faster than O(n log n) time?

Tags: time-complexity, heap, heapsort, binary-heap, binomial-heap

I was looking into binary, binomial and Fibonacci heap sort and I found out that takes O(n log n) time to sort. It would be great if someone can give me a reason as to why it is so.

Comment: Last I knew (which was a long time ago) this was still an unproven theorem.

Comment: Simple reason: Nobody has come up with a sorting algorithm that beats that. There is not currently, as far as I know, a law or whatnot that states that this is the theoretical minimum, it's just that nobody has managed to improve on it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Answer (score 4):

A list of `n` elements has `n!` permutations. One of these permutations is the correctly sorted one. A single comparison between two elements conveys only 1 bit of information and therefore can't possibly do any better than cutting the search space in half. So a lower bound on the number of comparisons needed to distinguish the correctly sorted permutation from all other permutations is `log2(n!) ∈ O(n log n)`.

Note that `log2(n!)` really is just a lower bound - it doesn't mean that it is actually possible to sort `n` number with exactly `ceiling(log2(n!))` comparisons. In fact, there are permutations for which you need a few more comparisons. But this doesn't matter if we are just interested in the asymptotic behaviour.

So you see that if we don't restrict ourselves to comparison-based sorting algorithms, the lower bound doesn't hold. (See e.g. bucket sort or radix sort.)